# What is the best way to select a paragraph starting with eg [1], [2] etc and ending when you reach the next number [x] to [x+1]

Tags: python

I am trying to select paragraphs that are numbered like so [1] [2] [3].  For a number of reasons the only accurate way to tell when a paragraph ends is when you get top the next paragraph start.

[1] paragraph text example.  This can have double line spaces in it.

[2] next paragraph

I am trying to start getting text at [1] and end at [2] or any paragraph number.
This seems like it should be simple but I am struggling with this.

This is what I have so far

```
workingT = text.splitlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(workingT):
         if re.findall(r"(\>\s+\[\d+\])", str(line).strip("_")): This finds the first paragraph
              paragraphCountTest = str(re.findall(r"\>\s+\[(\d+)\]", str(line))).strip("[]'")
                   if int(paragraphCountTest) == paragraphCount + 1: 
                        findParagraph(index, paragraphCount)
```

So this ugly code is finding start of paragraph [1] [2] or whatever. It is then finding the next paragraph which must be [currentparagraphnumber + 1].  The reason for this is a line can be in the paragraph that starts with an [number] and thinks this is a new paragraph. 
I can print out the first line of each paragraph in the string.  The problem I'm having is when I try and print out the lines after the first line until the end point which is the [n+1]

I then send what I have found to a method findParagraph(index, paragraphCount)
This is where I am trying to print each line in the selected paragraph. This is what I have

```
def findParagraph(index, paragraphCount):
parCount = paragraphCount + 1



  ind = index + 1


line = workingT[index + 1]
endOfParagraphCheck = r"(\>\s+\[" + str(parCount) + "\])"
print(endOfParagraphCheck)
                #if line != re.match(endOfParagraphCheck, str(line)):


for index, line in enumerate(workingT, start=ind):
    #print(line)
    print(workingT[index])
```

This isn't working.  I just want to loop though each line until I hit the next paragraph start.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using regex to find your start paragraph indicators.. .Im not sure if this is what you are looking for but this prints your individual paragraphs

```
data = """[1] [9]asdasdomthing
asdas
asd
asd 
asd
[2] sdfdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

[3] sfddsfdsfsd
sdfsdfsdf"""

import re

positions = []
# regex to indicate the values [1] or  [2] or ...
pattern = re.compile("\[\d\]")
# find positions in the string
prev=0
for match in pattern.finditer(data):
    current = data[match.span()[0]+1:match.span()[1]-1]
    if int(current)-int(prev) ==1:
        positions.append(match.start())
        prev = current

last_item=len(positions)-1
# loop throughpositions and print
print(positions)
for index, item in enumerate(positions):
    start=item
    if index != last_item:
        print('--------Paragraph--------------')
        print(data[item:positions[index+1]])
    else:
        print('--------Paragraph--------------')
        print(data[item:])
```

Ouptut is as below

```
--------Paragraph--------------
[1] [9]asdasdomthing
asdas
asd
asd 
asd

--------Paragraph--------------
[2] sdfdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff


--------Paragraph--------------
[3] sfddsfdsfsd
sdfsdfsdf
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks like it could work!  Only issue is if in paragraph [1]  there is a line starting with [9] for example it will find that as a new paragraph when I only want it to find the next numeric number [2] in this case and ignore [9].  I'm happy to give a tick based on your answer but will leave open for a bit until I figure out how to add that.

Comment: slight tweak to get around that problem. edited the code